# Enumerate and get the first item of each tuple?

Tags: python, loops, enumerate

How to get from this:

```
col = [('red', '132', '234'), ('green', '236', '434'), ('brown', '542', '457')]
```

to this:
**EDIT** (without any quotes)

```
1 red, 2 green, 3 brown   # enumerate and get the first item of each tuple.
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
[zip(((enumerate(col),1),i[0])) for i in col]
```

Only built-in functions please.

Comment: `[f"{i} {color}" for i, (color,_,_) in enumerate(col, 1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
>>> col = [('red', '132', '234'), ('green', '236', '434'), ('brown', '542', '457')]
>>>
>>> ["{} {}".format(index, first) for index, (first, *_) in enumerate(col, start=1)]
['1 red', '2 green', '3 brown']
```

Comment: can you please remove the quotes from the result and make it not be a list ?
See the edit.

Comment: @user17850871 You can just join the list `', '.join(["{} {}".format(index, first) for index, (first, *_) in enumerate(col, start=1)])`

Comment: The quotes continue to remain after that. Any ideas?

Comment: @user17850871 Did you `print(', '.join(["{} {}".format(index, first) for index, (first, *_) in enumerate(col, start=1)]))`?

Comment: right. ok thanks

Answer (score 1):

First use `enumerate` with an appropriate starting value. Next, unpack the resulting tuple to get just the values you need. Finally, use an f-string to create the desired string from the number and the color name.

```
[f"{i} {color}" for i, (color, _, _) in enumerate(col, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print([f"{i + 1} {each[0]}" for i, each in enumerate(col)])
```